# How to add specific columns to all text files in a directory in Linux?

Tags: linux

Can't find a solution, although thousands of variants of this question have been asked before. 
 I have several text files in a directory. I want to add one column to the beginning of each file. The added column for the first file is a column of 0's, for the second file it is a column of 1's, for the third file it is a column of 2's etc.

So, how to turn this:

```
   0 2 3 2  
   3 3 3 1
   4 3 4 2
```

to this:

```
0 0 2 3 2 
0 3 3 3 1
0 4 3 4 2
```

and this:

```
 2 3 4 3
 2 3 3 5
 5 4 1 2
```

to this:

```
1 2 3 4 3 
1 2 3 3 5 
1 5 4 1 2
```

in a loop?

I tried the following without any success:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=/prosjekt/tvs/QSexpt1_16K

jj=0
for file in "$path"/*.lsf;
do

awk '{$1=$(($jj)); print}' $file >> qq.txt
$jj=$(($jj+1))

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=/prosjekt/tvs/QSexpt1_16K

jj=0;
for file in "$path"/*.lsf; do
  awk "{printf \"$jj\"; print}" "$file" >> qq.txt
  jj=$(($jj+1))
done;
```

---

Problems in your try were: `$jj=$(($jj+1))` - you need to assign variable without `$`; bash variable won't expand into `''`.

Comment: Thans a lot! :)